# handlebars, {{#each posts}} disappears the blog page

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to change a blog website to be dynamic.
For that, I am using mongoDb and handlebars `{{#each ArrayName}}` to change it to a dynamic website.
When I try to do it with the data which I am taking from my mongoDb, and apply the handlebars code `{{#each ArrayName}}`, the body code disappears. But if I use static data, it will show in the page. Here is my handlebars code, after the `class="row"`, I used it.

```
                <div class="row">
                    {{#each Posts}}
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="blog">
                            <div class="blog-img">
                                <img src="img/blog2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog-content">
                                <ul class="blog-meta">
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span class="writer">John Doe</span></li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-clock"></i><span class="writer">{{date}}</span></li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-comments"></i><span class="writer">13</span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                                <p>{{content}}</p>
                                <a href="blog-single.html">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}
                </div>
```

And here is my one sample from sampleData.js

```
Post.create({
    title: "First post entry.",
    content: "This is the first content of post."
}, 
    (error,post) => {
    console.log(error,post)
})
```

Here is the Post.js code,

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    title: {type: String, require: true},
    content: {type: String, rqeuire: true},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})
```

And as last, here is my route code,

```
router.get("/blog" , (req,res) => {
    Post.find({}).then(posts =>{
        res.render("site/blog", {posts:posts})
    })
})
```

Why would I see the posts in the page when I'm using static data,
and why would I not see the posts in the page when I'm using dynamic data?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073967/3397771

Comment: @76484 I changed the find() with lean() and problem is still exists.

Comment: @76484 Also anymore it does not open the /blog anymore. There is a loading symbol on tab title.

Comment: @76484 Also i get that error in my terminal, 
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED',

Comment: First of all, `Posts` in your template should be lower-cased - `{{#each posts}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your route to use `async/await` with `Model.find().lean()` like so:

```js
router.get("/blog" , async (req,res) => { //< Note the use of async keyword
   try{
      const posts = await Post.find({}).lean(); //< Note the use await keyword
      res.render("site/blog", {
         posts:posts
      });    
   } catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      //Handle error
   }
})
```

When using handlebars `{{#each}}` helper, you need to use the `this` keyword [to reference the element being iterated over](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each). For example `{{this.title}}` or `{{this.content}}` so update your template like so:

```
<div class="row">
 {{#each posts}}
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="blog">
          <div class="blog-img">
             <img src="img/blog2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="blog-content">
             <ul class="blog-meta">
                <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span class="writer">John Doe</span></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-clock"></i><span class="writer">{{this.date}}</span></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-comments"></i><span class="writer">13</span></li>
             </ul>
             <h3>{{this.title}}</h3>
             <p>{{this.content}}</p>
             <a href="blog-single.html">Read More</a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
</div>
```

As mentioned in the comments by@76484 please make sure you use `posts` and not `Posts` in your handlebars template to loop through the array of `posts`.