# handlebars #each helper can't iterate correctly

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a handlebars snippet like below

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Message</th>
      <th scope="col">Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each result}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{@index}}</th>
      <td>{{this.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

result is an array from mongodb and present like below

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("651de76a44d50f1d9cfedede"),
    name: 'Lucy',
    message: 'I way',
    createdAt: 2023-10-04T22:30:02.377Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-10-04T22:30:02.377Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("651de7eca2da2627f94ce3cb"),
    name: 'Tanya',
    message: 'I like chemical',
    createdAt: 2023-10-04T22:32:12.465Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-10-04T22:32:12.465Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("651de8854ee4b125468e6921"),
    name: 'Otto',
    message: 'I from hightower',
    createdAt: 2023-10-04T22:34:45.179Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-10-04T22:34:45.179Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

if i replace {{this.name}} with {{this}} it'll show

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("651de76a44d50f1d9cfedede"),
    name: 'Lucy',
    message: 'I way',
    createdAt: 2023-10-04T22:30:02.377Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-10-04T22:30:02.377Z,
    __v: 0
  }
```

replace {{this.name}} with {{name}} won't work either (the block will keep blank)

Comment: Perhaps this post will be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073967/3397771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @76484's comment and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073967/3397771)

[handlebars API reference](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access)

> From version 4.6.0 on, Handlebars forbids accessing prototype properties and methods of the context object by default.

By changing mongoose query from `model.find()` to `model.find().lean()` it works properly.

> This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result documents are plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose documents.
> [mongoose doc: Faster Mongoose Queries With Lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to [how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696886/how-to-iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-handlebars), but in short, just lose the `this.` - it's implied as part of the `#each` (although the [documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) does not make this clear at all):

```
    {{#each result}}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{@index}}</th>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
```