# Handlebars not displaying array elements in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working on an Express.js application where I'm using Handlebars for templating. I have a route that fetches station data from MongoDB using Mongoose and passes it to a Handlebars template. While most of the data is displayed correctly, I'm facing an issue with iterating over an array in the template.

```
app.get("/Manager", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let stationData = await business.getStation(1001);
        console.log("Station Data:", stationData);
        console.log("Fuel Details:", stationData.Fuel);
        res.render('ManagerPage', {
            layout: undefined,
            station: stationData
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching station data:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
```

Handlebars Template:

```
<body>
    <h3>Station Details</h3>
    <h4>Name: {{station.Name}}</h4>
    <h4>Location: {{station.Location}}</h4>
    <h4>Manager: {{station.Manager}}</h4>
    
    <h3>Current Fuel Prices</h3>
    {{#each station.Fuel}}
        <h4>Type: {{this.type}}, Price: {{this.price}}, Remaining: {{this.remaining}}</h4>
    {{/each}}
    
    <a href="#">Delivery</a>
    <a href="#">Sales</a>
</body>
```

```
{
  "_id": new ObjectId('654b56af0a2d9b94b4b2c2fa'),
  "StationID": 1001,
  "Name": 'Woqod',
  "Location": 'Duhail',
  "Manager": 'Mubarak Al-Kuwari',
  "Fuel": [
    { type: 'Premium', price: 1.97, remaining: 100 },
    { type: 'Super', price: 2.01, remaining: 90 }
  ]
}
```

issue:
The station details are displayed correctly, but the fuel details, which are in an array, are not showing up on the rendered page. I've confirmed that the data returned by the getStation function contains the correct fuel details.

Comment: do you really need `this` inside your `each` for `type` / `price` / `remaining`. [How To: Handlebars - Iterate over Arrays with the Each Helper](http://jsdev.wikidot.com/howto:11) - **The each helper with an Array of JSON elements**

Comment: Can you post the code from `business.getStation`. Are you using `lean()` on your mongoose queries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebar template engine looping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071122/handlebar-template-engine-looping-issue)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `this` inside your `each` to access the properties `type`, `price` and `remaining` of the array `Fuel`.

The syntax for accessing properties inside the `{{#each}}` block in handlebars is `{{type}}`, `{{price}}`, and `{{remaining}}` without the `this` keyword:

```
{{#each station.Fuel}}
    <h4>Type: {{type}}, Price: {{price}}, Remaining: {{remaining}}</h4>
{{/each}}
```

Source: [How To: Handlebars - Iterate over Arrays with the Each Helper](http://jsdev.wikidot.com/howto:11)

Comment: You are correct but I don't think that is the issue. The `this` is implied when using the `each` helper so it should work with or without the `this`.