# How can I access object properties in my .hbs template?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a webpage that needs to display informations about `Cars` at a dealership.
All is well, except, I cannot access object properties from inside the `.hbs view template`.

Here's what I have:
1 - The `route` that renders the page:

```
router.get('/item', async function (req, res) {
    let car = await Car.findOne()
    console.log("Got one car to show: " + car)
    res.render('item', { car : car, layout: 'index' });
});
```

2 - inside the `item.hbs`, I want to display the information:

```
<h4 class="text-gray-dark mb-3">FOR RENT
   <strong>$ {{ car.priceModel }}</strong>
   PER DAY
</h4>
<h1 class="mb-3">
   <b class="text-gray-dark">{{ car.year }}</b>
   <span>{{{ car.model }}}</span> // I know I am using triple {{{}}} 
</h1>
```

3 - the problem is, `car.priceModel` and `car.model` don't display anything. If I were to use just `car`, it would output the whole object, as a `string`. so, I tried the following:

```
res.render('item', { car : JSON.stringify(car), layout: 'index' });
```

In this particular case, when using `{ car }`, I would get `[object Object]`, but still, trying to access `{{ car.model }}` **would yield no result**.

What am I actually doing wrong?
I have seen some tutorials working exactly like this and the `hbs` views rendered fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe this has to do with the type of object returned by `Car.findOne()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073967/3397771

Comment: @76484 you pointed me in the right direction, I solved this but I don't really like the solution. Is there a global way to specify the db query result of `findOne()` should always be a POJO? or do I have to use `lean()` for each object retrieval?

Comment: As far as I know you would have to use `lean()` for each object retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

After @76484 gave me a hint, I solved this by configuring `Handlebars` as follows:

```
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine({
    runtimeOptions: {
        allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
        allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true
    }
}));
```