Nodejs and Handlebars, parsing a string as an array
I am developing a website for a project. The main function of this website is to allow registered users to create, edit, and share wish lists that they create. This website is made using nodejs, handlebars as a view engine, and html/js for code. It uses mysql to log user info and list items. My list creation screen allows possibly infinite inputs by creating a new input field on the press of a button. It works as follows:
 addBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        
        const item_contianer = document.createElement('div');
        item_contianer.className = 'item-container';

        const item = document.createElement('input');
        item.type = 'text';
        item.id = 'item';
        item.name = 'item';
        item.placeholder = 'Insert Item Here';
        item.required = 'true';

        const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
        removeBtn.id = 'remove';
        removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';

        list.appendChild(item_contianer);
        item_contianer.appendChild(item);
        item_contianer.appendChild(removeBtn);

        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            this.parentElement.remove();
        });

    });

When I save this info in my database, it is saved as an string in the format of an array (["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"] by the following code:
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const listName = req.body.list_name;
    **const listItems = JSON.stringify(req.body.item);**
    
    db.query('INSERT INTO userlists SET ?', {id: decoded.id, listName: listName, listItems: listItems}, (err, results) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                return res.status(200).redirect('../view');
            }
    });
}

To access this info I read it from the table and send a JSON object to the page:
exports.view = async (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.cookies.jwt) {
        try {
            const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.jwt, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            db.query('SELECT * FROM userlists WHERE id = ?', [decoded.id], (err, results) => {
                if(!results) {
                    return next();
                }
                req.lists = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)));
                return next();
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

When I try to read this object I want to print the List name and then print each item in the string array on a seperate line as follows:
<div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>View a List</h1>
    </div>
    {{#each lists}}
        <div>
            <h3>{{listName}}</h3>
            {{#each listItems}}
                {{this}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
    </div>

I have tried converting 'listItems' into a JSON object with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listItems)) but it returns a parser error: Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'.
I've also tried just to parse it but it returs the same.
I am relatively new to most of this, especially handlebars so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Where is your res.render() call?

This is it: res.render('view', {lists: req.lists}); I have another file that handles renders that uses the exported data from the file with the code above.

If you log the value of lists from within your template with {{log lists}} what result gets logged?

It returns, this object: [
RowDataPacket {
id: 1,
listId: 13,
listName: 'List Example 1',
listItems: '["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"]'
}
]

id refers to the user, listId is just an identifier and listName and listItems speak for themselves.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073967/3397771
