Cannot loop an array in a handlebarsjs template
For some reason I cannot loop through the items array to display in my order confirmation email template the items, quantity and price of the customer order.
Any ideas what I'm I doing wrong? I've already tried with the this keyword and it didn't work.
This is my handlebars template:
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      style='background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); margin-top: 2.5rem; margin-bottom: 6rem; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 0.5rem; box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); margin-right: 8rem; margin-left: 8rem;'
    >
      <main style='position: relative; min-height: 100%;'>
        <div
          style='height: 20rem; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 50%; padding-right: 1rem;'
        >
          <img
            src='https://imagedelivery.net/-Kv3q_Rw64dJAsVUQLtKJw/09d99a13-814f-420f-fcac-dd14432d4e00/public'
            alt='LOGO'
            style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: center;'
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <div
            style='margin: 0 auto; max-width: 32rem; padding: 4rem 1rem 6rem; display: grid; max-width: 70rem; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)); gap: 2rem; padding: 8rem;'
          >
            <div style='grid-column-start: 2;'>
              <h1
                style='font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: 500; color: #6B46C1;'
              >Orden confirmada</h1>
              <p
                style='margin-top: 0.5rem; font-size: 2.25rem; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.2; color: #1a202c; font-size: 3rem;'
              >
                Gracias por ordernar</p>
              <p
                style='margin-top: 0.5rem; font-size: 1rem; color: #6b7280;'
              >Agradecemos tu pedido, actualmente lo estamos empacando. ¡Dentro
                de unos dias tu pedido estara contigo!</p>

              <div
                style='display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));'
              >
                <dl
                  style='margin-top: 4rem; font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: 500;'
                >
                  <dt style='color: #1a202c;'>Numero de orden</dt>
                  <dd style='margin-top: 0.5rem; color: #6B46C1;'>
                    <a href='https://ticogrinders.com/myOrders'>#{{orderId}}</a>
                  </dd>
                </dl>

                <dl
                  style='margin-top: 4rem; font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: 500;'
                >
                  <dt style='color: #1a202c;'>Numero de rastreo</dt>
                  <dd style='margin-top: 0.5rem; color: #6B46C1;'>
                    <a
                      href='https://correos.go.cr/rastreo/'
                    >{{trackingNumber}}</a>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
              </div>

              <ul
                role='list'
                style='margin-top: 1.5rem; border-top: 1px solid #e5e7eb; font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: 500; color: #6b7280;'
              >
              {{items}}
                <li style='display: flex; gap: 1.5rem; padding: 1.5rem 0;'>
                  <img
                    src='{{this.imageSrc}}'
                    alt='{{this.imageAlt}}'
                    style='height: 6rem; width: 6rem; flex: none; border-radius: 0.375rem; background-color: #f3f4f6; object-fit: cover; object-position: center;'
                  />
                  <div style='flex: auto; space-y-0.25rem;'>
                    <h3 style='color: #1a202c;'>
                      <a
                        href='https://ticogrinders.com/products/grinders/{{this.href}}'
                        style='color: inherit; text-decoration: none; transition: color 0.3s;'
                      >{{this.name}}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>{{this.color}}</p>
                    <p>{{this.size}}</p>
                    <p>Cantidad: {{this.quantity}}</p>
                  </div>
                  <p
                    style='flex: none; font-weight: 500; color: #1a202c;'
                  >₡{{this.price}}</p>
                </li>

              </ul>

              <dl
                style='space-y: 1.5rem; border-top: 1px solid #e5e7eb; padding-top: 1.5rem; font-size: 0.875rem; font-weight: 500; color: #6b7280;'
              >
                <div style='display: flex; justify-content: space-between;'>
                  <dt>Subtotal</dt>
                  <dd style='color: #1a202c;'>₡{{subTotal}}</dd>
                </div>

                <div style='display: flex; justify-content: space-between;'>
                  <dt>Envio</dt>
                  <dd style='color: #1a202c;'>₡{{shippingCost}}</dd>
                </div>

                <div style='display: flex; justify-content: space-between;'>
                  <dt>Impuestos</dt>
                  <dd style='color: #1a202c;'>₡{{taxes}}</dd>
                </div>

                <div
                  style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; border-top: 1px solid #e5e7eb; padding-top: 1.5rem; color: #1a202c;'
                >
                  <dt style='font-size: 1rem;'>Total</dt>
                  <dd style='font-size: 1rem;'>₡{{amount}}</dd>
                </div>
              </dl>

              <dl
                style='margin-top: 4rem; display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)); gap: 1rem; font-size: 0.875rem; color: #4b5563;'
              >
                <div>
                  <dt style='font-weight: 500; color: #1a202c;'>Direccion de
                    envio
                  </dt>
                  <dd style='margin-top: 0.5rem;'>
                    <address style='font-style: normal;'>
                      <span style='display: block;'>{{customerName}}</span>
                      <span style='display: block;'>{{customerCountry}}</span>
                      <span style='display: block;'>{{customerStreet}}</span>
                      <span style='display: block;'>{{customerStreet2}}
                        {{customerState}},
                        {{customerPostalCode}}</span>
                    </address>
                  </dd>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <dt style='font-weight: 500; color: #1a202c;'>Informacion de
                    pago
                  </dt>
                  <dd
                    style='margin-top: 0.5rem; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap: 1rem;'
                  >
                    <div style='flex: auto;'>
                      <p style='color: #1a202c;'>Ending with
                        {{lastFour}}</p>
                      <p>Expires {{expMonth}} / {{expYear}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </dd>
                </div>
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

By accessing the items object in the template I get this in the email
[{ id: '65b3e7fcd6d8153509988154', 
name: 'Ara La Lapa Roja', 
price: 15000, 
quantity: 1,
 size: 'Mediano',
 imageSrc: 'https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/product-page-02-secondary-product-shot.jpg\n',
 imageAlt: 'Two each of gray, white, and black shirts laying flat.', 
href: 'ara', 
_id: new ObjectId('66735a58e80bfff624d4c81d') 
},
{ 
id: '65b3e7fcd6d8153509988156', 
name: 'Onca La Jaguar', 
price: 15000, 
quantity: 1, 
size: 'Mediano', imageSrc: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2303/2711/files/2_e822dae0-14df-4cb8-b145-ea4dc0966b34.jpg?v=1617059123', 
imageAlt: 'Onca1', 
href: 'onca', 
_id: new ObjectId('66735a58e80bfff624d4c81e') 
}]

I already tried with
{{#each items}}
    {{imageSrc}}
{{/each}}

And I had no luck accessing the data, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
I did make sure the data I'm passing as the template context is an array.

I think this might be related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073967/3397771

you're iterating over an object so in your case "this" means the object current iteration, whole objects won't be output to the screen you need to dig out the right property.
{{#each items}}
    {{this.imageSrc}}
{{/each}}

giving "this iteration" a name is a bit more readable
{{#each items as | item |}}
    {{item.imageSrc}}
{{/each}}

verify you're accessing the right property of the object and that it exists, take a look at the helpers documentation for more information.
I'd also recommend using with to avoid rendering issues when a peice of data is missing.
{{#each items as | item |}}
    {{#with item}}
       {{imageSrc}} 
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html
hope I helped :)

the issue was me passing a db object response as part of the email context.
After casting the object into a variable I was able to access the data.
